# grep multiple characters in r

Tags: r

I have a list of files as below.

```r
files <- c("MD_KFL_ 201707_ 201906_gelabelt.csv", "MD_KFL_ 201707_ 201906_gelabelt.sav","MD_KFL_201707_201907_gelabelt_V78.csv", "MD_KFL_201707_201907_gelabelt_V78.sav")
```

I need to `grep` the  file names using only the following three unique names, i.e `201907`, `gelabelt`, `csv` so that in this case I have the output as `MD_KFL_201707_201907_gelabelt_V78.csv`.

Note that the order of the two unique names `201907` and `gelabelt` can differ sometimes.

I tried this so far.

```r
grep(paste(c('201907', 'gelabelt', 'csv'), collapse = '|'), files, value = T, fixed = F)
```

I can use

```r
grep('201907_gelabelt_V78.csv', files, value = True)
```

but the order of the elements in the source keeps changing month on month.

How can I achieve this in r without having to input the exact string format every time.

Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of `sapply` and `apply` where `tt` holds the names which should be in `files`:

```
tt  <- c("201907", "gelabelt", "\\.csv$")
files[apply(sapply(tt, grepl, files), 1, all)]
#[1] "MD_KFL_201707_201907_gelabelt_V78.csv"
```

or you use a non-consuming regular expression

```
files[grep("(?=.*201907)(?=.*gelabelt).*\\.csv$", files, perl=TRUE)]
#[1] "MD_KFL_201707_201907_gelabelt_V78.csv"
```

Comment: Thanks. Very elegant way of using grep and apply.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could use OR pattern here to take into account either of one word can occur first

```
grep("(201907.*gelabelt|gelabelt.*201907).*csv", files, value = TRUE) 
#[1] "MD_KFL_201707_201907_gelabelt_V78.csv"
```

so that it will also match when `"gelabelt"` occurs first.

```
grep("(201907.*gelabelt|gelabelt.*201907).*csv", "gelabelt_MD_KFL_201907.csv", value = TRUE)
#[1] "gelabelt_MD_KFL_201907.csv"
```